# Get cursor type from HCURSOR

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I get a HCURSOR from another process. I would like to find its type.
Its resource is of these [LoadCursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I looked around in MSDN site did not found any info about how to get resource id of the HCURSOR.
How do i do that?

Thank you.

Comment: i'm using my own software cursor, so SetCursor is useless to me.

Comment: what do you mean when you say "from another *process*"? and why would you "like to find its *type*"? what more specific type than HCURSOR do you have in mind?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf i basically want to check if a HCURSOR is system default arrow, resizeWE, move, wait etc...

Comment: This makes little sense.  You can get a cursor from a resource, it's one of the ways.  You cannot get a resource ID from a cursor.

Comment: This is a legit question and, before it was closed, it attracted a good answer that will help future visitors.  It should not have been closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't.  Cursors don't necessarily have resource IDs (you could create a cursor in memory, for example).

You perhaps could try creating cursors from known resource IDs and then comparing them to the `HCURSOR` in question. (System cursors should be used with `LoadImage(..., LR_SHARED)`, so multiple calls should return the same handle.)

Comment: i have no control over the other process.

i get an id like this MAKEINTRESOURCE(hCursor); which is not same id as the one listed in msdn site. but pointer is always 5 resizeWE is always 13 etc... these values never change even if program restarts. I make list of these to compare later. This seems to work, is this a valid way?

Comment: It is wrong to pass an `HCURSOR` handle to `MAKEINTRESOURCE()`. You should be calling `LoadImage()` with known IDs and then seeing if any of the returned `HCURSOR` values match the one that you already have, eg: `HCURSOR hSysCursor = (HCURSOR) LoadImage(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(OCR_NORMAL), IMAGE_CURSOR, 0, 0, LR_SHARED); if (hCursor == hSysCursor) { ... }`
`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I tried LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW) and it works, it is simpler than LoadImage.

Comment: @user1633272 the LoadCursor documentation says: "*Note: This function has been superseded by the LoadImage function.*"